# ABI stability on pointers to symbols vs regular symbol lookup

Tags: c++, linux, abi, dlsym

#### General Scenario

Using dlsym(), I dynamically load a shared object addon from my main thread.

I follow either of these two ways.

#### Way A

Pass a struct of pointers to symbols to the addon so it can call the host's functions and access other variables, knowing their data type of course.

#### Way B

Let the addon call symbols by their `extern "C"` identifier and have the runtime normally lookup them.

#### Question

Is there any difference between these two methods regarding ABI stability? For example: would one of this methods guarantee more chance of compatibility from an addon to the host program in case they were compiled in different environments?

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of "Way A" is that it gives you the chance to pass different pointers to different plugins.  So you could for example make a "v1" struct of pointers, and then later a "v2" that newer plugins could request.

Answer (score 0):

If anything works well two methods are equivalent except some performance loss. But runtime lookup resolves named symbols in global scope, which could be influenced by flag like `RTLD_GLOBAL` used in `dlopen`. It will lead to different behaviour under different context even though using the same addon.

So I think method A is better.